# Sandboxed code execution request failed

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am able to deploy other Sandbox Solution from Visual Studio 2010 but in one solution I am getting below error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Sandboxed code execution request failed.

In this solution I have added Feature Activated event receiver. In that I am creating lists and workflow association.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I can think of is workflow association you mentioned. Coded workflows are not allowed in Sandboxed Solutions. Still you can have declarative workflows.

Why don't you debug and see? Also check for ULS Logs and Event Viewer events.

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you try this way. You can Debug the Code and then you can find that where is the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx

Above Link shows how to deploy Sandboxed solution Manually and then debug it.